# LINQ - How project an object which was included with a hardcoded string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How to do projection of an object which was included with hardcoded string?

I have this query, and the MarcacaoFormularioMensagemRetificacao has to be added as a hardcoded string, since it's not a property of the previous objects:

```
 var query = db.Contacto.Where(c => c.idCidadao == idCidadao)   
    .SelectMany(c => c.Marcacao_Contacto)   
    .Select(mc => mc.Marcacao)  
    .Distinct()     
    .Where(m => m.id == idMarcacao && m.removida == false)  
    .Include(m => m.MarcacaoFormulario)     
    .Include("MarcacaoFormulario.MarcacaoFormularioMensagemRetificacao");
```

Later, I want to project this query into a list of objects of that class I included with a hardcoded string - I came up with something like this but I can only get to the MarcacaoFormularioMensagemRetificacao object using the select statement for all previous objects, as below:

```
 var retorno = query
                     .Select(m => m.MarcacaoFormulario
                     .Select(mf => mf.MarcacaoFormularioMensagemRetificacao
                     .Select(mfmr => new MarcacaoFormularioMensagemRetificacao
                     {
                        id = mfmr.id,
                        idMarcacaoFormulario = mfmr.idMarcacaoFormulario,
                        mensagem = mfmr.mensagem,
                        resposta = mfmr.resposta
                     }).Where(mfmr => mfmr.resposta == null)));


         return retorno;
```

The problem is that this does not returns a list of MarcacaoFormularioMensagemRetificacao, but a list, inside a list, inside a list, probably because of those many select statements in a row.
What´s the proper way to deal with this?
I'm working with EF 4.1, I guess there have been substancial progress since this version.

[List of list of list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwSPX.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can just change those `Select` for `SelectMany`:

```
var retorno = query
    .SelectMany(m => m.MarcacaoFormulario)
    .SelectMany(mf => mf.MarcacaoFormularioMensagemRetificacao)
    .Select(mfmr => new MarcacaoFormularioMensagemRetificacao
    {
       id = mfmr.id,
       idMarcacaoFormulario = mfmr.idMarcacaoFormulario,
       mensagem = mfmr.mensagem,
       resposta = mfmr.resposta
    })
    .Where(mfmr => mfmr.resposta == null)));

return retorno;
```

The second `SelectMany` doesn't seem to be needed, though. It would help if you posted the actual classes.

This will give you an `IQueryable<MarcacaoFormularioMensagemRetificacao>`. Notice that this doesn't execute the query (hence why you end up with `IQueryable`. If you want the results of the query, append a `.ToList()` at the end.